# SAML authenication with backbone SPA

Tags: http, backbone.js, single-sign-on, single-page-application, saml

We have some problems hooking our single page application written in backbone to a SAML authentication.
So here's wat we have (based on http://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/saml_guidance#planning-for-saml)
- the SPA is loaded
- first request to the back-end (SP) results in response telling it to redirect the IDP
- then the browser is at the IDP page. Basically our SPA is gone
- IDP redirects with a POST after successful login. This post contains stuff our SP needs to decode to login

Now the trouble we have is that post must be directed into the SP (back-end) and thus our SPA is not loaded. If we redirect (302) to our SPA, we cannot send authentication cookies. 
Am I missing something here?

Thanks for any pointers

Comment: Why cannot you send auth cookies when redirecting with a 302?

Answer (score 0):

We were obiously missing something. Our back end and front end were running on different nginx websites, with front looping through some parts to the back end. We had the IDP post back to a page on the backend domain, so the browser did not find any cookies on the front end domain.
Took us some time
Thanks!